# How to switch mac terminal between anaconda and miniconda?

Tags: python, macos, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, miniconda

I have installed Anaconda but the matpoltlib for python 3 did not work. So I tried to install miniconda.

```
$ jupyter notebook
```

then Jupiter notebook starts. But this message appears:

```
pyenv: conda: command not found 
The jupyter command exists in these Python versions:
  anaconda3-4.0.0
  miniconda3-4.1.11
```

How to choose miniconda?

Answer (score 0):

`conda` environments are the way to work with different Python versions.

Create new environment:

```
conda create -n py35 python=3.5
```

activate it:

```
source activate py35
```

Now, you can install the needed libraries:

```
(py35) conda install matplotlib jupyter
```

and start the notebook server:

```
(py35) jupyter notebook
```

Using this method, you can make more environments for other Python versions or combinations of library versions.

If `conda` refuses to start, you can use:

```
which -a conda
```

to see what `conda` commands are available.

Choose the full path you want, e.g.:

```
/Users/me/miniconda/bin/conda
```

to invoke `conda`.

Comment: I typed 'conda create-n py35 python=3.5' but the same came again 'pyenv: conda: command not found

The conda command exists in these Python versions:
  anaconda3-4.0.0
  miniconda3-4.1.11'

Comment: Sorry. Typo. Add a space: `create -n`.

Comment: the same comment came.

Comment: 'pyenv: conda: command not found

The conda command exists in these Python versions:
  anaconda3-4.0.0
  miniconda3-4.1.11'

Comment: Please start a new terminal and try again.

Comment: Added a possible approach to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found it

> $pyenv versions

In terminal this message will appear

> > system
> >
> > anaconda3-4.0.0
> >
> > miniconda3-4.1.11

next

> $pyenv global miniconda3-4.1.11
>
> $jupyter notebook